# Working out the angle of rotation from gyroscope data

Tags: c#, wii, wiimote

How can you use data from the gyroscope to work out the angle of rotation in x,y and z. I am using the gyroscope in the WiiMotion plus amd Brian Peek's Wiimotelib 1.8 beta library.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Deriving Angle Of Rotation From A MEMS Gyroscope](http://forum.pololu.com/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=3296) which includes sample code snippets.  You could also take a look at the general formula on Yahoo! Answers: [How do I determine the angle of rotation using a rate gyro?](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110324135052AA7edGz)

Content from Yahoo Answers post:

> Rate multiplied by time equals distance. If you travel at a rate of
>   50MPH how far did you travel in 1/2 hour. (25 miles)
>
> Same type of problem. if you move at a rate of 10 deg/sec for three
>   seconds you should have moved a total of 30 degrees. This of course
>   assumes that you kept a uniform rate for the entire three second
>   period. Now suppose that you measured 30 readings at 1/10th of a
>   second intervals and each reading indicated the same 10deg/sec rate.
>   The answer would be the same 30 degrees
>
> The difference between these two methods is the ability to detect
>   variations in rate across shorter periods of time. The faster you poll
>   the rate information the more accurate the overall reading will be.
>
> Rate readings should also have positive and negative values. Move left
>   its negative , move right its positive for example. You would then add
>   all of the readings and come up with a net result that should be very
>   close to the actual overall angle moved from the initial position.
>
> Problem with this method is that errors compound over time unless they
>   are zeroed out against a known point or reference periodically.
>   Polling rate information at a quicker pace minimizes the rate the
>   error builds up by capturing rate information before the unit has
>   experiences a large variation in rate. However variations still happen
>   and ultimately build up to a point where the computed angle is
>   erroneous. This is why the angle is periodically compared to a known
>   reference point and zeroed to it before such total error grow large
>   enough to become problematic.